# lodash compose with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a function which is working as is but I like to challenge myself with writing it in one line using lodash functions. I am having trouble getting this particular example working.

```
function sum(x,y) {
    return (+x)+(+y);
}

var a = function(e, f) {
    return Math.pow((e-f),2);
};

var x = _.reduce(arr, function(acc, v, k) {
    var c = Math.pow((v-m), 2);
    acc += c;
    return acc;
}, 0);

var m = 5;
var arr = [4, 2, 5, 8, 6]
```

I am expecting 20.

This is what I have been trying with no luck:

```
_.reduce(arr, _.partial(sum, _.partialRight(a, m)), 0);
```

yields NaN.  So I thought maybe I can compose the first function with sum:

```
_.reduce(arr, _.compose(_.partialRight(a, m), sum), 0);
```

yields 131044.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your original function is already "one line, using Lodash functions":

```
var x = _.reduce(arr, function(acc, v, k) { return acc + Math.pow(v-m, 2); }, 0);
```